# Find mean degrees of graph communities, including links between communities

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I'm finding the mean degrees of graph communities like this:

```
(*Build a 50% complete random network with 30 vertices*)
G = RandomGraph[{30, Floor[0.5 Binomial[30, 2]]}];
GC = FindGraphCommunities[G];
(*Make a list of community subgraphs*)
GCL = Table[Subgraph[G, GC[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[GC]}];
(*Find the mean degrees of the community subgraphs*)
Mean /@ VertexDegree /@ GCL // N
```

The problem is that this only counts edges within the subgraphs and omits edges linking subgraphs in the overall graph. Is there some way to also include those links in the mean degree calculation for each community?

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this was pretty simple:

```
(*Build a 50% complete random network with 30 vertices*)
G = RandomGraph[{30, Floor[0.5 Binomial[30, 2]]}];
GC = FindGraphCommunities[G];
(*Find the degrees of every vertex in the network*)
GD = VertexDegree[G];
(*Select out the degrees of the nodes in each community*)
GCVD = Table[Part[GD, GC[[i]]], {i, 1, Length[GC]}]
(*Average*)
Mean /@ GCVD // N
```